# mongoose nodejs "Unknown modifier: $pushAll"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I am taking this course, but I can't seem to fix my problem, I get 
`{
    "name": "MongoError",
    "message": "Unknown modifier: $pushAll",
    "driver": true,
    "index": 0,
    "code": 9,
    "errmsg": "Unknown modifier: $pushAll"
}`
when I try to make a new user. I looked it up and it said too add
`{
  usePushEach: true
});`
to my mongoose's schema settings which I did, but it still errors and I can't seem to fix it here is the code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  email: {
    require: true,
    type: String,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      validator: validator.isEmail,
      message: `{VALUE} is not a valid email`
    }
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    minlength: 6
  },
  tokens: [{
    access: {type: String, require: true},
    token: {type: String, require: true}
  }]
},{
  usePushEach: true
});

UserSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function() {
  var user = this;
  var access = "auth";
  var token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id.toHexString(), access}, "abc123").toString();
  // user = user.concat({access, token})
  // console.log(user)
  user.tokens.push({access, token})

  return user.save().then(() => {
      return token
  })
};

var User = mongoose.model("User",  UserSchema);


module.exports = {User};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at [mongodb official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/pushAll/) `$pushAll` had been deprecated since v2.4.

In latest mongodb version *(3.6)* `$pushAll` does not exist anymore.

> Use the $push operator with $each instead.

---

If you want to force the use of `$pushAll`, a solution is given in [this thread](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5574)

[image]

---

Real answer to the problem is :

> @SkylarLopez hm... I would look at your version of mongoDb and
>   mongoose. See if they match, maybe you have an unappropriate mongoose
>   version that use $pushAll in it .save method

Comment: I'm a bit confused though, I'm not using the $pushAll operator in my code, so how would I replace it

Comment: @SkylarLopez hm... I would look at your version of mongoDb and mongoose. See if they match, maybe you have an unappropriate mongoose version that use `$pushAll` in it `.save` method

Comment: Right, I have that in the code I posted, the {usePushEach: true} to try to get it to work before, but it still does not

Comment: You where right, I needed to update my package, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 tokens: [{
    access: {type: String, require: true},
    token: {type: String, require: true}
  }]
```

**try this**

```
 tokens: {type: Array, require: true}
```

Comment: how you are calling this function ?